# JSTL loop in JSP for nested unrodered lists

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

MVC - servlet forwards request to JSP.
In servlet i created list (java.util.List) of categories, attached this list to servlet context, and forwards request to JSP page:

```
public class Category{
       private Integer id;
       private String name;
       private Category parentCategory;
       ...
       //getters and setters
    }
```

This class represents category/subcategory (if parentCategory field is null, then it is top level category).
Categories that have same parent, are its subcategories, and they are mapped to nested unordered list in JSP.
Example: result should look similar to next HTML code:

```
<ul class="droprightMenu">  
            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a>
                <ul class="droprightMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1.3</a></li>
                          <ul class="droprightMenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Category 1.3.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 1.3.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 1.3.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 1.3.4</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                <ul class="droprightMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Category 3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 3.2</a></li>
                          <ul class="droprightMenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Category 3.2.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category 3.2.2</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">Category 3.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 3.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I don't know how to loop through this list in JSP. It should probably be done with some combination of different JSTL loops, or JSP scriptlets, maybe some recursion. 
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to populate your Model like this:

```
public class Category{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private Category parentCategory;

   private List<Category> subCategories;

   ...
   //getters and setters
}
```

In Servlet, You need to have LIST of Category LEVEL 1 ( Parent is NULL ).

```
List<Category> rootCategories = getAllCategoriesLevel1();
request.setAttribute("rootCategories",  rootCategories );
```

In JSP ( Need 3 loops OR 4,5 loops )

```
<c:forEach items="${rootCategories}" var="categoryLevel1">

    // ...

    <c:forEach items="${categoryLevel1.subCategories}" var="categoryLevel2">

        // ...

        <c:forEach items="${categoryLevel2.subCategories}" var="categoryLevel3">

            // ...  

        </c:forEach>

        // ...

    </c:forEach>

    // ...

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can use <c:if test="${not empty xxxx.subCategories}"> to wrap c:forEach statement. You have to limit your Max level. Let say your max level is 5, You has 5 loops in JSP. Because you already use <c:if so It works fine if there is a menu that less than 5 levels.

Comment: OK, lets say there is a list(or a set) of subcategories in class Category. But, again, i don't know exact level how deep will subcategories go, how many foreach nested loops. So, how should look some JSTL loop patern that will cover all subcategories, not only until specific level?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the depth of the category tree, you can still generate your menu using recursion.

Using the same Model as Loc in the previous response, you have to define a jsp page called `menuitem.jsp`, which will be called recursively:

```
<li>
   <a href="#">${menuitem.name}</a>
   <c:if test="${fn:length(menuitem.subCategories) gt 0}">
      <ul class="droprightMenu">
         <c:forEach var="menuitem" items="${menuitem.subCategories}">
           <c:set var="menuitem" value="${menuitem}" scope="request" />
           <jsp:include page="menuitem.jsp" />
         </c:forEach>
      </ul>
   </c:if>
</li>
```

In our main JSP page, initialise the variable menuitem and include the jsp.

```
<c:set var="menuitem" value="${rootMenu}" scope="request" />
<jsp:include page="menuitem.jsp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I didn't know how to implement this recursively, so i have limited categories depth level to three (see my answer). But now, I will consider your option.

Answer (score 2):

```
<c:forEach var="rootCategory" items="${allCategories}" varStatus="rootCategoryLoop">
    <c:if test="${rootCategory.rootCategoryId eq product.rootCategoryId}">
        <c:forEach var="category" items="${rootCategory.categories}" varStatus="categoryLoop">
            <c:if test="${category.categoryId eq product.categoryId}">
                <c:forEach var="subCategory" items="${category.subCategories}" varStatus="subCategoryLoop">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${subCategory.subCategoryId eq product.subCategoryId}">
                            <div>${subCategory.subCategoryName}</option>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <div}">${subCategory.subCategoryName}</option>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>  
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if> 
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have limited subcategories level - to level 3.
So, this is the code in servlet:

```
// findAll() - returns all categories in database, as a list
List<Category> categories = categoryDao.findAll(); 
ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
servletContext.setAttribute("categories", categories);
```

And these are the loops in JSP page, where am i extracting data from list and generating html markup:

```
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
            <ul class="droprightMenu">
                <li><a href="#">All</a>
                    <ul class="droprightMenu">

                        <!-- first loop, extracting categories level 1  -->
                        <c:forEach items="${categories }" var="catLevel1">

                            <c:if test="${catLevel1.getParentCategory()==null }">
                                <li><a href="#">${catLevel1.getName() }</a> 

                                <!-- second loop, extracting categories level 2  -->
                                    <ul class="droprightMenu">
                                        <c:forEach items="${categories }" var="catLevel2">

                                            <c:if test="${catLevel2.getParentCategory().getId()==catLevel1.getId() }">
                                                <li><a href="#">${catLevel2.getName() }</a> 

                                                <!-- third loop, categories level 3  -->
                                                    <ul class="droprightMenu">
                                                        <c:forEach items="${categories }" var="catLevel3">

                                                            <c:if test="${catLevel3.getParentCategory().getId()==catLevel2.getId() }">
                                                                <li><a href="#">${catLevel3.getName() }</a></li>
                                                            </c:if>

                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </ul></li>
                                            </c:if>

                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </ul></li>
            </ul></li>
```